# What is accessible using an Apple ID?

Tags: iphone

If get an Apple ID, what can I access?

Can I download example games, access the necessary developer information, or any other help with the Objective-C language such as tutorials?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  Are you asking about what you get by joining the developer program?  All of that is spelled out on Apple's site and has been discussed here many times before.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the Apple Developer connection, then yes, you can get access to all the documentation, example code and tutorials with a free Apple ID.

Some other resources, like videos, require a paid membership to the Apple Developer Connection.

Also, why did you tag your question with cocos2d and then not mention anything to do with it?